# How do I generate scripts for all tables with single stroke in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

How do I generate scripts for all tables with a single stroke in SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 43):

You can't do this with one click of a button.

You have to:

- Right click Database
- Select All Tasks > Generate SQL Scripts
- Click Show All
- Check All Tables
- Click the Formatting tab. Select the options you require
- Click the Options tab. You may want to script out the Indexes, Full-Text Indexes, Triggers, Primary & Foreign Keys.
- Then choose whether you want it all in one file or one file per object.

Comment: I guess it was just a race to see who could write out those steps quickest :-)

Comment: @Damien - Yes it is one of those types of questions.... Fastest finger first! :)

Comment: thanks friends, its very useful